# use the sum method to get the sum of the squares of odd numbers between 1 and 1000

Tags: python

```
n=1000

squares = n

for x in range(1,n+1,2):

    square = x**2

    squares.append(square)

mysum=(squares)

print("sum of squares of odd integers between 1 and ", n, " is ", mysum)
```

I'm creating this loop in order to list the sum of squares of odd numbers between 1 and 1000. not exactly sure what to set as the "squares" value, as I'm getting a response "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'".

Apologies if this sounds dumb. I'm new to Python.

Comment: You can't append to a number. Are you thinking of using a list for `squares`? If you are, use `squares = []` on line 3.

Comment: that was exactly the issue - I knew I couldn't append to a number, however I didn't think of leaving the list blank in order to give values from elsewhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The below will give you the sum of all odd numbers squared from 1 to 999.

```py
sum(x**2 for x in range(1,1000, 2))
```